# Problem of existing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Let $n,k \geq 2$ be two integers. Prove that there must exist some $n \times n$ invertible, non-diagonal matrices: $X_1,X_2, \dots , X_k$ with real entries, such that $$X_1^{-1}+X_2^{-1}+\dots+X_k^{-1}=(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_k)^{-1}$$

Since this is a problem which asks to construct the matrices, I tried to make it less general. I tried to find some matrices with $X_i^2=I_n$ and hence $X_i^{-1}=X_i$, so what would be left to take care of is the equality $(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_k)^2=I_n.$

For the case when $k$ is odd, I chose $X_1$ to be the matrix with $1$ on the antidiagonal and $0$ anywhere else; then for $X_i=(-1)^iX_1,\: i \geq 2$ the problem is solved.

However, I have problems when $k$ is even. I couldn't find such matrices even when $k=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=2$ we could take

$$
X_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
X_2=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\beta -1\cr \beta & -\alpha \end{pmatrix}.\;
$$
Then we have 
$$X_1^{-1}+X_2^{-1}=(X_1+X_2)^{-1}$$
and $X_1^2=X_2^2=I$ if and only if 
$$
\alpha^2=\beta^2+\beta+1.
$$ 
A special case is $\beta=1$, with $\alpha^2=3$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may be silly and not see something easy, but could you please elaborate a little bit more the general solution?

Comment: I have made it more explicit now.

Comment: Thank you! Can this be extended for higher $n$ and also for $k \geq 4$ where $k$ is even?

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry to come back with another question: I tried to construct two matrices for $n=3: \: X_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X_2=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\beta-1 & 0 \\ \beta & -\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$ These satisfy $X_1^2=X_2^2=I_3$, but $(X_1+X_2)^2 \neq I_3$? What is the right construction for this case? For general size $n$ I initially thought of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \dots \\ 1 & 0 & \dots \\ \vdots & \vdots & I_{n-2} \end{pmatrix}$, but it doesn't work...

Comment: For even size it works to take block matrices with the above $2\times 2$-matrices (so no identity matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses complex numbers. Let us note the association 
\begin{align}
a+ib \longleftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence it suffices to consider solutions to 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z_1+z_2} = \frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2}  \implies -1 = \frac{z_1}{z_2} + \frac{z_2}{z_1} = z + \frac{1}{z}.  
\end{align}
In  particular, let us focus on solutions lying on the unit circle. Hence we get
\begin{align}
-1 = e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = 2\cos \theta 
\end{align}
which means $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ is a solution, that is,
\begin{align}
\frac{z_1}{z_2} = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}} = -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}. 
\end{align}
Let us choose $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}$, then the corresponding matrices 
\begin{align}
X_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
X_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
satisfy the relation
\begin{align}
(X_1+X_2)^{-1} = X_1^{-1} + X_2^{-1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

How about assuming $X_i = Q \Lambda_i Q^T$ for some unitary matrix $Q$? If $\Lambda_i$ is not a scaled identity, these matrices are non-diagonal. Moreover, you have $X_1 + ... + X_k = Q(\Lambda_1 + ... + \Lambda_k)Q^T$ and $X_i^{-1} = Q \Lambda_i^{-1} Q^T$. This reduces your problem back to diagonal matrices which means you only need to find scalars $\lambda_{i,j}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{\lambda_{i,j}} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{i,j}}$ for all $j= 1, ..., n$. You could try to work from there. Just an idea.